# InfoPath field change with rules

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form (2010) and on the bottom of my form I made a Draft Button, and a Submit Button. My first field on the form is called the Form Status, which is a drop down menu with two choice "Draft or Submitted," it is defaulted as a DRAFT. On my Submit button , there is a data connection to a library which enables a workflow, and I attached a ruled to it that after submit : Change Field status(Form Status) to value "Submitted," it is not changing when the form is submitted. Any ideas? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you using a SharePoint Designer Workflow? If yes, check the Form Status if it is allowed to be edit. This will make the field editable by the workflow. To change it, go to File - Publish - SharePoint Server. On the wizard, click next until you get to the Column promotion. Add/Modify the Form Status field and you will see an option at the bottom: "Allow users to edit data in this field by using datasheet or properties page". Check that option and then finish the publishing. The workflow can now edit the field.

On another scenario, if you are talking about just simple rules without workflow. I think you should put the Form Status change before the submit data connection. Any rules after submit data connection are not saved.

Comment: So what u stated in the other scenario is what I'm trying to get to work and I had it the way you said and still not working . Thank you so much for your suggestions